# Is there any way to find the exact order in which the events of an Ext Js 4.2.0 component are fired?

Tags: extjs4.2

I would like to know how can I find, for example, which is the very first event which fires when I click on a certain tab of a tab.Panel in Ext Js 4.2.0, and if possible the exact order of the events involved when a user clicks on a tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start by reading the docs for components. Should be able to help you:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/components